# Using CSS transitions to animate dynamic SVG Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to animate the attributes of various SVG shapes using JavaScript and CSS transitions.

For example:

HTML:

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <circle id="circle" cx="200" cy="200" r="15" stroke="none" fill="blue" />
    <rect id="rect" x="100" y="100" height="30" width="30" stroke="none" fill="red" />
</svg>
<button id="button">Animate</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
    var cx = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
    var cy = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
    // using 'setAttribute'
    circle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", cy);

    var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
    var x = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
    var y = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
    // using 'setAttributeNS'
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
}, false);
```

CSS:

```
circle, rect {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here's a complete JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkhvzyjq/

In Chrome, this works beautifully. However, in Safari and Firefox, while the new attributes are applied (the shapes move), there's no transition/animation.

Is there a way to do this that works in these browsers?

Comment: do the whole thing in SMIL

Comment: @RobertLongson - I tried, but couldn't get that to work. Specifically - if I added two `animation` elements to a `circle`, for example, and used JavaScript to modify the `from` and `to` attributes - it didn't work. (I.e., the animation didn't recommence each time I changed the attributes). I also tried removing old animation elements and adding new ones with new `from` and `to` attributes, but that didn't work either. In other words, I could only get SMIL animation to work when it's added at author-time, not modified dynamically during runtime.

Comment: You wouldn't do that, you'd just begin the animation onclick

Answer (score 2):

Safari and Firefox do not transition changes in the position attributes.

The CSS property `transform` works better for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkhvzyjq/7/

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  var cx = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
  var cy = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
  circle.style.transform = "translate(" + cx + "px," + cy + "px)";

  var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
  var x = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
  var y = 50 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300);
  rect.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)";
}, false);
```

```css
circle,
rect {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <circle id="circle" r="10" stroke="none" fill="blue" style="transform:translate(200px,200px);" />
  <rect id="rect" height="10" width="10" stroke="none" fill="red" style="transform:translate(100px,100px);" />
</svg>
<button id="button">Animate</button>
```